# Client side pagination using angular js

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I am trying to implment `pagination` using [angular-pagination](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/03/client-side-pagination-using-angular-js.html) but instead of `ul` and `li` I am using `table` and `tr`.

1 - can I do it?

2 - Is it the reason that pressing `next` is not working?

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/prash/Cp73s/330/)(without `jQuery`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do it. try like this.

```
<table class="pagination-controle pagination">
 <tr>
     <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="curPage == 0"
         ng-click="curPage=curPage-1"> &lt; PREV</button></td>
     <td>Page {{curPage + 1}} of {{ numberOfPages() }}</td>
     <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
      ng-disabled="curPage >= datalists.length/pageSize - 1"
     ng-click="curPage = curPage+1">NEXT &gt;</button></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```